# Facebook login php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make a login page for v2.8 graph api.

I am following all the graph api examples but still getting an error.

This is the error:

```
Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data.
```

**fbaccess.php**

```
session_start();

$app_id     = "xxxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxx";
$site_url   = "http://xxxxxxxxx/";

require_once __DIR__ . '/src/autoload.php';


// Create our application instance
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => $app_id,
'app_secret' => $app_secret,
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);
```

**index.php**

```
session_start();


include("fbaccess.php");


$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes']; // optional
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://shortbucks.com/facebook/callback.php', $permissions);

 echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

**callback.php**

```
session_start();

include("fbaccess.php");


$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();  


 try {
 // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken(); 
 $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', $accessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
 echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
 exit;
 } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

$user = $response->getGraphUser();

echo 'Name: ' . $user['name'];
```

Can someone help me identify the error?

Thanks

Comment: you can find some information about this with google: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/issues/473

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem, i have downloaded the last version of SDK from Facebook and voila works perfect.. cheers